# Existing Query works - I need to add a column from another table

Tags: sql

I have an Existing Query that gives the required result - but I need to add a column from another table and still get the same 203 rows...when I try to join to that table I get a thousands of rows...

```
select a.state, a.alternate_id, a.reg_id 
from altid1 a, altid1 b 
where a.alternate_id=b.alternate_id 
and a.reg_id <> b.reg_id 
group by  a.state, a.alternate_id, a.reg_id
having count(a.alternate_id)>1
order by state, alternate_id,reg_id;
```

this gives me the state and each alternate id that has multiple reg_ids...now I need to add two owner fields that do not exist in the altid1 table

I need to join to the owner table and get the same 203 results just with the additional columns...the owner table DOES contain the reg_id column but how can I match on that when I'm trying to get the ones which have different reg_ids in the original table?

```
select a.state, a.alternate_id, a.reg_id, c.owner1, c.ownertype1 
from altid1 a, altid1 b, owner c 
where a.alternate_id=b.alternate_id 
and a.reg_id <> b.reg_id
group by  a.state, a.alternate_id, a.reg_id, c.owner1, c.ownertype1
having count(a.alternate_id)>1
order by state, alternate_id, reg_id;
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: add c.id = a.id in the where cluase.

Answer (score 0):

try t his one, make sure you change [id column] to the actual field name and a or b the table has got the relationship with c table.

```
  select a.state, a.alternate_id, a.reg_id, c.owner1, c.ownertype1 
    from altid1 a, altid1 b, owner c 
    where a.alternate_id=b.alternate_id 
    and a.reg_id <> b.reg_id
    and c.[id column] = a or b . [id column] -- change id column to actual id field from the table and change a or b to the correct table having relationship with c table.
    group by  a.state, a.alternate_id, a.reg_id, c.owner1, c.ownertype1
    having count(a.alternate_id)>1
    order by state, alternate_id, reg_id;
```

Comment: Thank you,

I tried that with:

   and c.reg_id = a.reg_id

this returned 2213 rows - so something is being duplicated - the altid1 table only has 787 rows...of which I was pulling 203...

please note that the a and b tables are actually the same table - I'm just trying to get the rows that have multiple reg_ids for each alternate_id

Comment: if you can, please show us ur tables structures that way we can see what exactly going on.

Comment: Table Structure for altid1 - this is a temp table created for one state only and contains 720 rows
Thank you

STATE 1  Y VARCHAR2 (6 Byte) 
REG_ID 2  Y VARCHAR2 (30 Byte) 
ALTERNATE_ID 3  Y VARCHAR2 (30 Byte)

 
Table Structure for owner - this table contains many thousands of rows for many states

STATE 1  N VARCHAR2 (6 Byte)  
REG_ID 2  N VARCHAR2 (30 Byte) 
LEGAL_1 3  Y VARCHAR2 (60 Byte)  
LEGAL_2 4  Y VARCHAR2 (60 Byte)  
LEGAL_3 5  Y VARCHAR2 (60 Byte)  
OWNER1 6  Y VARCHAR2 (40 Byte)  
OWNERTYPE1 7  Y VARCHAR2 (3 Byte)

Answer (score 0):

When you added `owner` to the tables you're selecting from you didn't add an additional join condition. This means your performing a cross join between your original 203 row result and `owner`.

A cross join between two tables `A` and `B` returns a row for each possible pair of rows with one in `A` and one in `B`. So if `A` has `n` rows and `B` has `m` rows, `A` cross join `B` has `m*n` rows. Not good.

What you need to do is add an additional clause to your where statement. I can't tell exactly what that would be from your code. Is there some column that links `owner` to `altid1`?

But, perhaps more importantly, **don't use comma joins**. They make it very easy to accidentally create cross joins and lots of other horrible horrible things. If you accidentally do a cross join on a large database you can end up with millions of rows in no time.

Instead use the where clause only to filter the result and join additional tables using the standard `JOIN` syntax.

Your original query would become:

```
select a.state, a.alternate_id, a.reg_id 
from altid1 a
inner join altid1 b
   on a.alternate_id = b.alternate_id
where a.reg_id <> b.reg_id 
group by  a.state, a.alternate_id, a.reg_id
having count(a.alternate_id)>1
order by state, alternate_id,reg_id;
```

Then your new query would look something like this (I'm just making a guess on what links `owner` to `altid1`):

```
select a.state, a.alternate_id, a.reg_id 
from altid1 a
inner join altid1 b
   on a.alternate_id = b.alternate_id
inner join owner c
   on c.owner_id = a.owner_id
where a.reg_id <> b.reg_id 
group by  a.state, a.alternate_id, a.reg_id
having count(a.alternate_id)>1
order by state, alternate_id,reg_id;
```

Note that I've used inner joins! I can't tell from you question whether `owner` should be brought in with an inner join or a left join. The short explanation of the difference is that inner join won't include rows where a matching row in `owner` can't be found.

P.S. **don't use comma joins**

Comment: There is no owner_id for table a  Thank you

Comment: @user2836119 It was just a placeholder. I don't know what your schema looks like.